# Allow Users Access to Custom Post Type Only

Tags: custom-post-types, functions, capabilities, user-access

I am in a similar situation to [this person](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14553/allow-member-to-have-access-to-custom-post-type-only-permission-to-only-edit-the), only I need a bit more hand-holding. I don't have a good understanding of php but can cut and paste code with the best of them.

I have Justin Tadlock's [Members](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/members/) plugin, and have set up a custom post type and associated custom taxonomies in my functions.php file.

Here's what I'm trying to accomplish:

- User registers and is set as
  **Contributor** by default.
- User can now see **only** this custom post type
  and can make an entry to this post
  type, but not publish it.
- User can only see and edit their
  own post(s).

If possible, I need specifics on what and where to add to my post type registration function. I understand it involves 'map_meta_cap' and 'capability_type' but I don't know how to write the code or where to put it in the function. Once the capabilities are established I can add them as custom capabilities in the Members plugin.

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out on my own -- the code snippet I needed to follow is [here](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2010/07/10/meta-capabilities-for-custom-post-types). Justin Tadlock is the man.