# Can multiple authors be assigned on a single custom post?

Tags: custom-post-types, author, multi-author

I have custom post types that I would like to make editable by several users. I created one custom post type using the Toolset plugin. `wp_update_post` only allows us to set single author:

```
$user_id = array();
$userIds = get_field("agency_to_author",$_POST['post_ID']); // Get Multiple User assing using acf field.
foreach ($userIds as $key => $value) {
     $user_id[] = $value['ID'];
}
if(!empty($user_id)){
     $arg = array(
         'ID' => $_POST['post_ID'],
         'post_author' => $user_id,
     );
     wp_update_post( $arg );    
}
```

Comment: This might help: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/29009/how-to-assign-specific-users-the-capability-to-edit-specific-pages-posts-cus?rq=1

Comment: I am looking for custom post types that I would like to make editable by several users

Answer (score 0):

Easy way: use this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/

More complicated way: You can use functions.php to add all of the custom capabilities to a specific roles. But ofc you need a name of these capabilities.

This code is usefull if you want to add X same capabilities to X roles.

Add to functions.php

```
   function wphm_add_custom_capabilities_to_roles($roles, $capabilities) {
     foreach($roles as $the_role) {
       $role = get_role($the_role);
       foreach($capabilities as $capability) {
         $role -> add_cap($capability);
       }
     }
   }

  wphm_add_custom_capabilities_to_roles(
    array(  // these roles will recieve capabilities
      'custom_user_role_wphm_support',
      'administrator'
    ),
    array( // capabilities
      "read_wphm_custom",
      "read_private_wphm_custom",
      "edit_wphm_custom",
      "edit_others_wphm_custom",
      "edit_published_wphm_custom",
      "publish_wphm_custom",
      "delete_others_wphm_custom",
      "delete_private_wphm_custom",
      "delete_published_wphm_custom"
    )
  );
```

To remove a capability with this loop just modify a line  $role -> add_cap($capability); to  $role -> remove_cap($capability)

Comment: I want to assign multiple author on single custom post type is it possible with wp_update_post function or any other way?