# Disable user from updating certain posts

Tags: custom-post-types, users, user-roles, capabilities

I have a custom post type with a certain amount of posts. What I have to do is to disable users from editing/updating certain posts of that post type, but not all of them.

I have to do that programmatically, so please **no plugins**.

Any ideas?

Users that are disallowed from updating/editing certain posts need to have the ability to read them.

Answer (score 0):

You should use different roles for this groups of users, like CPT-Editor or CPT-Reader. It is much easier to check the role and his capabilities to change on posts. To change this capabilities in the roles use a plugin, like Members, or custom code. The capability for edit, read cpt is different, in dependence of your plugin, that add this CPT.

[This question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14553/allow-member-to-have-access-to-custom-post-type-only-permission-to-only-edit-th) is really helpful in this context, via plugin and custom code is a answer deposited.