# How to allow some visitors to edit inline specific post

Tags: posts, editor, visual-editor

I would like to allow some determined people to be able to edit a determined post via the front end.

For example, let say, I have two posts A & B then I want Alice to be able to edit post A but not post B. And I want Bob to edit post B but not post A.

Does any of you have a perfect solution for me?

If not, my plan is to code a little plugin w/ the following feature:

1. Create & send a unique token for Alice and Bob.
2. A table to store the token
3. Activate an inline editing plugin when it’s the good token

Does anyone see an easier way?

Regards,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Allow member to have access to custom post type only. Permission to only edit their own posts](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14553/allow-member-to-have-access-to-custom-post-type-only-permission-to-only-edit-th)

Comment: Hello

Thank you, but in my case, Alice and Bob are not registered on my website !

Comment: I see. I think is an important information and you should add it in your question. Also why avoid user registration etc? I mean you offer a service to a user, right ? Thank you.